# Lost my reputation and badges after email update

Tags: support, reputation, badges, accounts, merge-accounts

I had two accounts. I had **95 reputation with 13 badges** in **email1** and just **16 reputation with 3 badges** in **email2**.

What I did is I updated my email from **email1** to **email2** and verified it. I did it by mistake. After that I am able to login from both emails but **my reputation was decreased to 90 and badges decreased to 8**. What is the reason? Can I undo this operation?

Comment: Did you possibly originally answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935485/overlay-in-bootstrap-4-figure-img-only/50936363#50936363) or another one with the second account, or have accidentally upvoted an answer from one of the accounts to the other? Take a look at your [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4010449/milan-bastola?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2018-06-19%2022:01:33Z) to see if there's anything that should be there that isn't, or is there that shouldn't be. As for the badges, do you still meet the requirements for the 5 badges you "lost"?

Comment: Also I see you as having 11 badges, not 8, maybe it's just caching catching up.

Comment: reputation history is blank and badges are increasing one by one. I think it will be okay.

Comment: They should remember what it's like to be struggling to gain the initial rep points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your reputation history, I don't see you ever hitting 95 reputation with your main account. In the logs, it shows you at 70 reputation on June 16, and you received a single 10-point upvote yesterday. Your other account had a reputation of 16 this morning, when the two were merged into a single 90-reputation account.

I don't even see you losing reputation from when I deleted the unrelated account [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416186/gallery-disappears-in-mobile-view) yesterday, due to the age of your answer. At first I thought that might have something to do with this, but it doesn't look like it.

Beyond the badges, which might simply be an artifact of caching, I don't see anything anomalous here.

Comment: SO has great customer service :) I like it